# How to get include url in Filter

Tags: java, jsp, jspinclude

In my JSP page `index.jsp` I have

```
<c:import url="/hello.jsp?name=user" />
```

I have a filter which is mapped to `hello.jsp`, how do I get the include url in this case `/hello.jsp?name=user`. If I try request.getUrl(), it gives me `/index.jsp`.

Comment: The method `getUrl()` doesn't exist. Please be more explicit to prevend red herrings.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch it using [`getQueryString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

It's been sent as a request parameter. Just use [`ServletRequest#getParameter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) to get it.

```java
String name = request.getParameter("name"); // "user"
// ...
```